# python pandas dataframe on grouping resulting in two columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df`:

```
PID    AID    Ethnicity
1      A      Asian
1      B      Asian
1      C      Arab
1      D      African
2      A      Asian
2      D      African
2      E      Caucasian 
2      F      African
2      B      Asian
```

I want to generate a frame that tells me for each `PID` how many `AIDs` it has, and how many Ethnic groups:

So for the above the resulting `newdf` would be:

```
PID    numAID    numEthnicities
1      4         3
2      5         3
```

I know how to find numAID:

```
newdf = df[['PID','AID']].groupby('PID',  
as_index=False).count().rename(columns={'AID':'numAID'})
```

I'm not sure how to add the third column to the `dataframe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
df.groupby('PID').agg({'AID':'count','Ethnicity':pd.Series.nunique}).add_prefix('num')

     numAID  numEthnicity
PID                
1      4          3
2      5          3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a third column like this:

```
newdf['numEthnicities'] = df[['PID, 'Ethnicity']].groupby('PID', as_index=False).count()
```

Comment: this will give you how many authors as well, not how many ethnic groups. It should be groupby(['PID','Ethnicity']) I believe

Answer (score 0):

since you have found out `newdf`, you could try to use [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) function.)

```
df = df.set_index('PID')
newdf = newdf.set_index('PID')
result = df.join(newdf, lsuffix='df', rsuffix='newdf')
```